# Why do these constraints seem to lag when animated?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I am animating my constraints using `UIView.animate`. `drawerHeight` is a constraint variable.

Here is the code:

```
drawerHeight?.constant = newHeight

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.65, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

[Here is a video of what the issue looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdZFD.jpg)

Looking at the bottom of the video, the bottom edge appears to lag behind. **Why do these constraints seem to lag when animated?**

*This is a self-answered question. This post is to help people in the future discover what they did wrong, and how to quickly fix it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the constraint was attached to a view in a deeper hierarchy than before. When using `layoutIfNeeded()`, it should be called on the superview of the view containing the constraints.

In my situation, I put the view with the `drawerHeight` constraint within another `UIView`, which made it deeper in the hierarchy.

I fixed the issue by doing

`self.superview?.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` ,

instead of

`self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` .